# Possible to get Bloomberg API into Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bloomberg

Is there a version of [blpapi](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/) for python 3?  If not, has anyone successfully modified the existing SDK to make it work (or do you just start from scratch and write an interface to the C++ version?).

Some background:
The existing Bloomberg API (free to the public, but needs to be downloaded from the Bloomberg website) facilitates queries of Bloomberg's database and market data feeds from python.  The official Bloomberg version seems to only work for <= 2.7.

Comment: He is asking if there is a Python 3 version of the files here. http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

Answer (score 3):

Finally it has been released, now I can move to Python 3

http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/

This is the 64bit version for Python 3.4
http://static.bloomberglabs.com/api/python/blpapi_python_3.9.0.win-amd64-py3.4.exe

Answer (score 2):

I've created a python 3 branch of the API you may be interested in:

https://github.com/filmackay/blpapi-py/tree/py3/blpapi

Answer (score 0):

MathMonkey, as of now, you can see the binary supported by Bloomberg on this page: http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

There is no API for Python 3.3 officially supported at the moment.